# + operator in Java 7 performance and behavior

Tags: java-7

Does + operator behave like stringbuilder in JDK 7 ?

In terms of creating a string, does it create new immutable strings or appends to the same object ? Is it the same/different in terms of performance as well ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does + operator behave like stringbuilder in JDK 7 ?

[There is an optimization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.2) that will automatically turn `String` concatenations into `StringBuilder`s (in some cases).

> In terms of creating a string, does it create new immutable strings or
>   appends to the same object ?

If you have a bunch of data strung together with `+`, it will create a new immutable `String` literal:

```
System.err.println("" + 5 + " hello foobar" + "...");
```